# Smart caption by UILabel or UITextView

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, uilabel, uitextview, sizetofit

I would like to create a smart caption as SoundCloud app did.
See the attachment below,

[image]

These two captions:
- •PAN•
- Berlin, Germany

are what I want create.

These captions seem to be executed by sizeToFit or sizeThatFits. However, if using sizeThatFits with background colour (by NSBackgroundColorAttributeName), you won't get padding both before the first and after the last letters and top and bottom paddings as well.
The caption will be organised the exact fit size as these letters.

[image]

Anyway, what I would like to do is the exact same caption like the attachment picture.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You have two approaches here. One is to add a bit of padding after calling `sizeThatFits`. The other is to prepend and append a space to your label title.

The right way about adding the padding, though, would be to extend `UILabel` and on your subclass, override the method `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:`. In there, just call the same method on `super` passing the `bounds` you receive, only smaller.

Comment: Thank you for your advices. I will try to test according to your flows. Will let you know if working! If you don't mind, share a snippet of example code with me?

Answer (score 0):

I know is an old question but i was looking for the same effect that SoundCloud has on its labels. 
here is the subclassing of uilabel

```
    import UIKit

    class LabelPine: UILabel {

override func drawTextInRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let insets = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 5, left: 0, bottom: 5, right: 3)
    super.drawTextInRect(UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, insets))
}

override func textRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect, limitedToNumberOfLines numberOfLines: Int) -> CGRect {
    super.textRectForBounds(bounds, limitedToNumberOfLines: 0)

    return CGRectInset(self.attributedText!.boundingRectWithSize(CGSizeMake(999, 999), options: .UsesLineFragmentOrigin, context: nil), -5, -5)




    }
}
```

And here is the implementation on the respective class:

```
   labelNombre = LabelPine()
    labelNombre?.text = nombreUser
    labelNombre?.frame = CGRectMake(10, nombrePos.Yo, nombrePos.ancho, nombrePos.alto)
    labelNombre?.font = UIFont(name:"Hiragino Sans W3",size: 19)!
    labelNombre?.textAlignment = .Left
    labelNombre?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.5)
    labelNombre?.textColor = colorBlentUIColor
    labelNombre?.sizeToFit()

    header?.addSubview(labelNombre!)
```

Take notice i call sizeToFit().